# Produce Response Time Graph with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, response-time

I am working on Apache Jmeter. I am going to simulate DOS attack with this software, and measure the Response Time / Experiment Time. I should produce these factors with Graph. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/

It uses [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) that you easily install following this [procedure](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/).